# Making sublime save new files out with LF lineendings despite being run on windows?

Tags: newline, text-editor, sublimetext2

I'm running sublime text on windows right now, and every time I create a new codefile and save it, it always comes out as `CRLF`, no matter how many times I set the menu option to "unix".

I'd like to set sublime to never ever ever write another file out with windows line endings again, to the extent it's possible.

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `default_line_ending` in your settings file to `unix` as shown in the simplified example below. The settings file can be found in the "Preferences" > "Settings" menu option.  This will apply to new files. Here's a little snippet from my preferences file with it set to "unix".

```
{
    // Determines what character(s) are used to terminate each line in new files.
    // Valid values are 'system' (whatever the OS uses), 'windows' (CRLF) and
    // 'unix' (LF only).
    "default_line_ending": "unix",
}
```

There is some additional [documentation of this on the sublime text site](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html?highlight=default_line_ending).